# dd/mm/yyyy date format not supported by Sitecore Forms date field in IE11

Tags: sitecore-forms

When using the Sitecore Forms date field in an Australian website - the date format of dd/MM/yyyy does not work in IE11.  Seems to be a client side issue.

[image]

I tried implementing a fallback as per this post:
https://gist.github.com/sunnydoll/759a5cdf49f495feab1b

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.14.5/polyfiller.js"></script>

<script>

    webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {types: 'date'});
    webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
    $.webshims.formcfg = {
        en: {
            dFormat: '/',
            dateSigns: '/',
            patterns: {
                d: "dd/mm/yy"
            }
        }
    };

</script>
```

It works once after the page has loaded, but on submitting the form - the form is cleared out but the date picker no longer seems to be initialised.  I imagine its related to ajax/partial postback but haven't figured out the missing piece of the puzzle.

[image]

Comment: Hi have you found the solution? I have the same problem

Comment: @Vsn Unfortunately not - it got deprioritised in the list of things to look at. I have since moved on.  Hope you find a solution :)